# Adding Default value to oracle database with high volumes of data

Tags: oracle10g, default-value

I am trying to add a new column to a table with upwards of 9 million records.

This issue is the column needs to be default value of 'N'. When updating the table the database is getting an issue with the temp data being filled. Also, it is taking a huge amount of time.

I was wondering if anyone knows of anyway to make this faster or a better way of doing this to avoid problems with the temp data filling up.

The database is Oracle10g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could move to 11g and the column was `NOT NULL`, Oracle has an optimization where the default value doesn't need to be stored in each row so you can add the column very quickly.  Unfortunately, it sounds like you're stuck with a depricated version of Oracle where that isn't available.

Most likely, you don't have a lot of really good options other than waiting.  It may be more efficient, assuming you're doing this during a period of downtime, to create a new table with the new column, do a direct-path insert of all the data from the old table to the new table, rename the tables, and re-point any constraints at the new table.  Whether this is actually more efficient than waiting for the update will depend on your hardware and your table but an `INSERT` is likely to be more efficient than an `UPDATE`.  On the other hand, for a new single-character column that isn't going to create a lot of migrated rows, you're probably better off waiting for the `UPDATE` rather than going to this level of effort-- there are a lot of things that could potentially go wrong that you'd need to test and validate (i.e. making sure that you updated all the constraints correctly).